# While running ansible playbook on jenkins, it is giving error: TimeoutError: Timer expired after 20 seconds

Tags: shell, jenkins, ansible, ansible-facts

I am running my ansible playbook on Jenkins server. It is running fine. But the same playbook while I am running in Jenkins, giving error:
*TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: TimeoutError: Timer expired after 20 seconds
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "/usr/sbin/udevadm info --query property --name /etc/auto.r", "msg": "Timer expired after 20 seconds", "rc": 257}
to retry, use: --limit @/install/scripts/tet1.retry*

I am running this playbook in execute shell in Jenkins.
'''ansible-playbook /install/scripts/test.yaml'''

I have configured ansible.cfg with gather_timeout = 20/30/50/!all. Tried every combination, still facing this issue.

Comment: What happens when you execute udevadm info .... on the remote servers manually?

Comment: I ran:  /usr/sbin/udevadm info --query property --name /etc/auto.r
device node not found